# Azure Bicep roleAssignments not found

Tags: azure-bicep

I'm trying to debug an idempotency issue.  I created a simple bicep module to create a role assignment.  Then I immediately try to get the role assignment using the existing option.  One interesting thing I noticed is that the bicep module ''br/public:authorization/resource-scope-role-assignment:1.0.2' uses 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments@2022-09-01' to create the role assignment.

But I'm trying to use 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' to find it afterwards.

Here is my code:
`

```
// Assign the KeyVaultAdministrator role to the SIS group.
module roleAssignmentOperator 'br/public:authorization/resource-scope-role-assignment:1.0.2' = {
  dependsOn: [ appGatewayResourceGroup ]
  scope: resourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
  name: 'sbx-test-agw-kv-ra'
  params: {
    name: guid(SISGroupId, KeyVaultAdminRoleId, appGatewayKeyVaultName)
    principalId: SISGroupId
    resourceId: appGatewayKeyVaultResourceId
    roleDefinitionId: KeyVaultAdminRoleId
  }
}

// Check to see if the KeyVaultAdmin role assignment for SIS already exists
resource roleAssignmentExists 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' existing = {
  name: guid(SISGroupId, KeyVaultAdminRoleId, appGatewayKeyVaultName)
  scope: resourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
}
```

`

Which results in this error message:
[{"code":"RoleAssignmentNotFound","message":"The role assignment 'b77673a7-42af-5a7f-891c-244333a44d38' is not found."}]

I have output the guid from the create step and it is 'b77673a7-42af-5a7f-891c-244333a44d38'.

Anybody have any idea why it is not being found?

Thanks.

George

This is all because in some of our pipelines, creating a role assignment is idempotent but in others it is not.  I'm trying to determine what is causing this difference.

Comment: it should work the second time you run your deployment. the first time you need to wait for the role to be created before being able to query it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Let me clarify that my code is just a snippet from the whole and that it doesn't matter if I wait some time or if the role assignment already exists.

The weird thing I'm trying to unravel is why doesn't it find the role assignment when I use the exact same GUID that was used to create it.

Answer (score 0):

***Need to check below:***

I see you are using `@2022-09-01 api version` for `Microsoft.Resources/deployments` and `@2022-04-01 api version` for `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments`. Make sure that both versions are identical and compatible.  It is possible to have a conflict as a result of this in some cases.

Check that the `principalID` is correctly passed in the bicep code. And also check that the `service principal ID` you are passing is not expired. In place of principal Id, you need to pass the object Id by going to the below path.

***Path:***

Go to

`Azure AD >> Enterprise Applications >> Search for your registered app >> Copy the object ID`.

After all of the above steps, I tried your requirement in my environment and was successful without any errors.

```bash
var appgw_service_name = 'newgw'
param principalId string = 'xxxx' 
param keyVaultResourceId string = 'xxxx' 
param resourceGroupName string = 'Jahnavi'
var roledefId = '/subscriptions/subscriptionID/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/00482a5a-887f-4fb3-b363-3b7fe8e74483' //Keyvaultadministratorrole ID
resource appgw 'Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways@2023-04-01' existing = {
  name: appgw_service_name
}

module roleAssignmentExample '.module' = {
    name: 'sbx-test-agw-kv-ra'
    scope: resourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
        params: {}
}

resource keyVaultAdminRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-08-01-preview' existing= {
    name: guid(principalId,roledefId,keyVaultResourceId)
    scope: resourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
}
```

*Bicep module file:*

```bash
param principalId string = 'xxxx' 
param keyVaultResourceId string = 'xxxx' 
param resourceGroupName string = 'Jahnavi'
var roledefId = '/subscriptions/subscriptionID/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/00482a5a-887f-4fb3-b363-3b7fe8e74483' 
resource keyVaultAdminRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-08-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(principalId, roledefId, keyVaultResourceId)
  properties: {
    principalId: principalId
    roleDefinitionId: roledefId
  }
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]